# Assign two values into one dynamic increment variable using jolt spec

Tags: json, specifications, jolt

I need to assign two values into one dynamic increment variable using jolt spec. I am trying the code below but I am getting an error

```
"JointOwner_*": {
            "$": [
        "case.Relation.TrusteePrimaryBeneficiary_clone_&5_(6,1)&3.RelatedObjectID",
 "CloneTrusteeBeneficiaryParticipants_(6,1)_&5[&1].TrusteePrimaryBeneficiary_clone_&5_&(6,1)&3.ExistingClient"
            ]
        }
```

Comment: reformatted code and clarified grammar

Answer (score 0):

What is the error message?

Also `"CloneTrusteeBeneficiaryParticipants_(6,1)_&5[&1].TrusteePrimaryBeneficiary_clone_&5_&(6,1)&3.ExistingClient"`

looks like it might have a problem with the `"[&1]"` as `&1` needs to at runtime evaluate to an integer.   In your example, &1 would evaluate to whatever string `"JointOwner_*"` matched.